# Valid ways of setting points in structure

Tags: c, pointers

```
typedef struct {
  int x,y;
} items;

void foo(items* i1, items* i2) {
  items item1 ={i1->x, i2->y};
  item1.x = 5;
  item1.y = 6;
  *i1 = item1;
}
```

Is this a valid way of setting everything in i1 to the the items in item1? or do I need to access each item in i1 and set them separately?

Comment: So what do you see when you look at the `i1` field values in a debugger and/or print them out? Are they what you expect them to be?

Comment: This is all valid.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid but not needed. Your example can be reduced to:

```
void foo(items* i1) {
  i1 -> x = 5;
  i1 -> y = 6;
}
```

Comment: Please use the standard conventional pointer notation without spaces, e.i. `i1->x`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie it is a personal preference. There is no `standard conventional pointer notation without spaces`.